# mySQL Update field dependent on Select

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update a record in one table that is dependent on a row in another table. Something like this:

```
UPDATE product_description SET description="" /* Nothing! */

WHERE product.product_id=product_description.product_id AND product.manufacturer_id=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE product_description 
JOIN product ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id 
SET description = "" /* Nothing! */
WHERE product.manufacturer_id = 1
```